# Turn dataframe from one condition (categories) to another (unpivot with split string by separator)

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

Help me, please, to turn this dataframe:

```
№   column1     column2
0   client|1    city|5
1   city|1      client|2
2   client|2    car|2
3   flower|3    city|4
4   flower|1    car|1
```

into this:

```
№   client  city    flower  car
0   1       5       
1   2       1       
2   2                       2
3           4       3   
4                   1       1
```

I tried something like this:

```
df.column1.values[0].split("|")
```

it gives me 2 lists:

```
['client', '1'] and ['city', '5']
```

But I can't imagine how to make dataframe to know, in what column to put appropriate value.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you create this dataframe from some source or this is the actual data?

Comment: Vishnudev, I composed the data values, but the data structure is the same as in the reality.

Comment: It would be easier to create the dataframe from the actual data.

Answer (score 0):

This helped:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    of = df.iloc[i:i+1,:]
    af = of.column1.values[0].split("|")
    bf = of.column2.values[0].split("|")
    df6.loc[i, af[0]] = af[1]
    df6.loc[i, bf[0]] = bf[1]
```